# Creating a page that displays a product matching a criteria

Tags: magento2

What I'm trying to achieve is creating pages which displays a range of products when a user clicks on a HTML Anchor, and looks the same as my search results page (when using the top bar), only allowing me to display results which match my criteria exactly (The theme I'm using doesn't have an advanced search feature, which I could manipulate the URL).

For example, one criteria of mine is "Pack Size", which is how many T-Shirts are in a given pack. If a user clicks on "10 T-Shirts", it will navigate to a page showing all products with a pack size of 10.

Would creating a seperate blocks for each desired result achieve this?

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

You are recreating layered navigation.
What you want is a standard category view, with all products. Using the root catalog will work for this.

Next you want to setup your attributes to be allwed as filters.

The end result would be a standard category list page, allowing your users to select filters.

You should be able to create this without any code. Tge main issue could be a theme that does not support layered navigation. Which would be odd.

Hope that helps.